# do-release-upgrade - 1 release before the -d

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I was on xenial, and did a 'do-release-upgrade'. It did nothing.

I wanted to upgrade to artful, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

so I did 'do-release-upgrade -d' and it brought me up to 'bionic' which I suppose I can deal with for a few months, but I didn't want to be quite as 'bleeding edge'.

But if I was able to go back in time, and do the right thing, is there a way to tell do-release-upgrade to go to a specific release? or 1 before the -d release?

Comment: There is NO tested and supported upgrade path from 16.04 to 17.10, which is why do-release-upgrade refused to do it. The supported path is to clean-install 17.10.